# How to compare timestamps between different time zones?

Tags: c#, extension-methods, datetime-format

If you have to deal with DateTime objects from different time zones - let's say because your web application is running on one server in the East Coast and another one in the West Coast - and you want to make sure that you are not making a mistake when you compare two timestamps (which customer clicked first, for example) then it comes in handy to have a method that does this for you.

A typical test case could look like this:

```
namespace ImageServerTest
{
    [..]
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestOrIfLater()
    {
        var PST = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time");
        var EST = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
        var t0 = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var t0p = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(t0, PST);
        var t0e = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(t0, EST);
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        var t1 = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var t1p = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(t1, PST);
        var t1e = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(t1, EST);
        Assert.AreEqual(t1, t0.OrIfLater(t1));
        Assert.AreEqual(t1p, t0p.OrIfLater(t1p));
        Assert.AreEqual(t1e, t1e.OrIfLater(t1p));
        Assert.AreEqual(t1e, t0p.OrIfLater(t1e));
        //Assert.IsTrue(t1p > t0e); //fails
        //Assert.IsTrue(t1p.Ticks > t0e.Ticks); //fails
        Assert.AreEqual(t1p, t1p.OrIfLater(t0e));
    }
}
```

Obviously, t1 is younger than t0 (meaning t1 > t0 or t1.Ticks > t0.Ticks) and t0p/t0e and t1p/t1e are their representation in PST/EST. Therefore, for a global perspective we would expect

```
t1p > t0e
```

and also

```
t1p.Ticks > t0e.Ticks
```

The test case specifies that we want to make sure that an extension method named **OrIfLater** always returns the younger timestamp (the one further on the right in the timeline).

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should be using `DateTimeOffset` when dealing with timezones and data comparisons. It was added to the BCL for that purpose.

Your existing code asserts produce the following values:

```
True
True
True
True
False
False
False
```

But if you change over to `DateTimeOffset`, like this:

```
TimeZoneInfo PST = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time");
TimeZoneInfo EST = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
DateTimeOffset t0 = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
DateTimeOffset t0p = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(t0, PST);
DateTimeOffset t0e = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(t0, EST);
Thread.Sleep(100);
DateTimeOffset t1 = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
DateTimeOffset t1p = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(t1, PST);
DateTimeOffset t1e = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(t1, EST);
Assert.AreEqual(t1, t0.OrIfLater(t1));
Assert.AreEqual(t1p, t0p.OrIfLater(t1p));
Assert.AreEqual(t1e, t1e.OrIfLater(t1p));
Assert.AreEqual(t1e, t0p.OrIfLater(t1e));
Assert.IsTrue(t1p > t0e);
Assert.IsTrue(t1p.Ticks > t0e.Ticks); //still fails
Assert.AreEqual(t1p, t1p.OrIfLater(t0e));
```

...then you get this result:

```
True
True
True
True
True
False
True
```

Of course you need to change your extension method from using `DateTime` to using `DateTimeOffset`.

There is still one failure for the `Ticks` property comparison. But this isn't a bug. It's how this property works.

If you look at the [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.ticks%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you'll see the following details:

> The number of ticks in the DateTimeOffset object's clock time.
>   The Ticks property is not affected by the value of the Offset property.

So to check this is I output the result of `new [] { t0, t0p, t0e, t1, t1p, t1e, }.Select(x => x.Ticks)` then I get this:

```
635955882954740587 
635955630954740587 
635955738954740587 
635955882955751105 
635955630955751105 
635955738955751105
```

The `Ticks` are indeed relative to local time and not the underlying UTC time. That final failing `Assert` is invalid.

However, if you change it to `Assert.IsTrue(t1p.UtcTicks > t0e.UtcTicks);` it works fine.

Comment: Great. I like it. DateTimeOffset it is.

Answer (score -1):

```
namespace Stuff
{
    public static class DynamicHelper
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// returns the latest date/time of the two, based on universal time
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="a">this timestamp</param>
        /// <param name="b">the parameter timestamp to compare with</param>
        /// <example>var latest = yesterday.OrIfLater(today);</example>
        /// <returns>the most recent of the two timestamps</returns>
        public static DateTimeOffset OrIfLater(this DateTimeOffset a, DateTimeOffset b)
        {
            return a.UtcTicks > b.UtcTicks ? a : b;
        }
    }
    [..]
}
```

Comment: is this supposed to be part of the question?

Comment: Well, the question was to provide an extension method named `OrIfLater` that provides the correct comparison result (always the timestamp that is later). Thus: No, it's supposed to be an answer.